# Check if 2 arrays are similar without hashing or sorting

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

We need to check if 2 arrays are similar or not. The elements can be duplicate as well.
For example A = {2,3,4,5,6,6} and B = {3,6,2,4,6,5} are similar.

I have a naive solution :

```
foreach i:int in arr1
 foreach j:int in arr2
  {
    if(i == j)
     j = -1;
  }
```

Now if all the elements of j are -1 , then we can say that the 2 arrays are similar. Can someone give a test case in which this won't work (i hope it should work though!) ?

Also this is O(n^2). Can we do better ? Sorting and Hashing are not allowed.

Comment: Why do you list 3 languages? Perhaps your looking for [language-agnostic](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/language-agnostic/info)?

Comment: Do you have to estimate or to be sure?

Comment: Not homework ! Relisted to just algorithm

Comment: I think `j` is both an int and an array (you refer to the "elements of j"), which makes your question hard to understand.

Comment: @Cygal What i am basically doing is that updating elements of B whenever a match is found , if all elements are matching then all the elements will be -1 , in that case the arrays will be similar. Hope you get it now.

Comment: @NiteeshMehra: your algorithm fails on trivial A = { 1 } and B = { -1 }.

Comment: Ah, so i and j refer to elements. It makes sense! I just assumed they were indices.

Comment: You can reduce it (but the worst case will still be O (n^2)) if every time you have a match you move the element to the end and set it to some symbol like NaN; then you check when you reach there to end the process.

Comment: @IgorKorkhov Right. I can take another array say bool c[] and set it to "true" in case a[i]=b[i]. Should work then i suppose.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do any better **without sorting and hashing**. Even Igor's solution is basically just a very memory-inefficient form of hashing (with hash := value).

Comment: @Heinzi: I also think that it can't be done any better without sorting/hashing, but I don't know how to strictly prove that.

Comment: @IgorKorkhov: We'd need to formally define the class of "algorithms which do not use sorting or hashing", which I think would be extremely difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a binary search tree that you build from one of them.
Now go over the other one and check if the value is already in the binary search tree.
This one runs in O(nlgn) and use O(n) space.

Comment: length of both array has to be same for them to be similar.

Comment: Great! It's not hashing nor sorting. The implementation must handle non-unique values but it's not hard and the complexities stay the same.

Comment: @AviCohen , generating the BST == sorting isn't it?

Comment: @DavidCosta It is equivalent to sorting. Generating a BST. Then for searching we need in order traversal which is == sorting.

Comment: @NiteeshMehra I didn't think of the solution as a sort, indeed it is.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in O(max(L<sub>A</sub>, L<sub>B</sub>)) *time*, where L<sub>A</sub> and L<sub>B</sub> are lengths of A and B, respectively, but at the price of using O(M) *space*, where M is an allowed range of values in the arrays (i.e. there are such constants `min` and `max`, so that `min <= a, b <= max` holds true for every a in A and b in B).

```
seen = array[min..max]
foreach a in A
    seen[a] = 'a'

foreach b in B
    if seen[b] != 'a'
        // A didn't contain b
        return "A and B are not equivalent"
    else
       seen[b] = 'a,b'

foreach s in seen
    if s == 'a'
        // A did contain a which was not in B
        return "A and B are not equivalent"

return "A and B are equivalent"
```

This approach is practical if the arrays are very large, but all their values fit in a small range.

Comment: @Heinzi: you are absolutely right, this is a bucket sort in disguise :)

Comment: @IgorKorkhov it works ,but like i mentioned `sorting` and `hashing` are not allowed

Comment: @NiteeshMehra: well, strictly speaking it is not sorting since it does not keep track of a number of elements seen so far. Bucket sort counts the number of elements in each bucket in order to return sorted sequence at its final stage, while my algorithm doesn't. Having said that, I agree that my algorithm is a half-baked bucket sort.

Comment: @NiteeshMehra: just curious, if it's not a homework or a brain-teaser, why is the restriction?

Comment: @IgorKorkhov This is equivalent to hashing !

Answer (score 0):

A = {2,3,4, 5,-1,6} and B = {3,6,2,4,6,5}

you should add **break** in your if-statement, without it your code will work only is there is no duplicates

Comment: After iteration B = {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,5} , so they are not similar !

Comment: @NiteeshMehra oh, there must be A = {2,3,4, 5, -1,6} and B = {3,6,2,4,6,5}, sorry =)

Comment: @NiteeshMehra what do you mean by "the same"? B = {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,5}? It can't be

Comment: @NiteeshMehra: Well, probably Alecs meant **B** = {2,3,4, 5, -1,6} and **A** = {3,6,2,4,6,5}.

Comment: breaking is also wrong, you will always skip the second encounter of the duplicate in B, since `j` will never reach it and fulfil `i==j`, because you terminated the run when you found the first element in B.

Comment: @IgorKorkhov this variant too, but without break A = {2,3,4, 5,-1,6} and B = {3,6,2,4,6,5} must also give B = {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1, -1} in result

Comment: @Alecs why would it give {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1, -1} ? It will give {-1,-1,-1,-1, 6 , -1}
For(i=0 to lengthA) A[4]!=B[i].

Comment: @NiteeshMehra A[4]==B[0],A[4]==B[2],A[4]==B[3],A[4]==B[5] 'cos they are already -1

Answer (score 0):

i just want to mention that u don't have to run your algorithm(whether it has  a complexity of o(n*m) or max(n,m)) for all input combinations.Run your algorithm only if xor of all the elements of both arrays is equal to zero.
i.e a[0] xor a[1] xor...b[0] xor...b[n]=0.
otherwise u can surely say that array A and B  is not equal.

Comment: That is xor of all elements of a should be equal to xor of all elements of b ?